# Ambari server can not register ambari agents

Tags: hadoop, ambari, hdp

I want to install hadoop cluster with ambari server, but following error occurs

**Registering with the server...

Registration with the server failed.**

**Steps**

1. I have manually installed ambari agents on two slave hosts
2. Then I have ran agent services on slaves.
3. Provided ambari-server's ip in agent config file
4. Provided FQDNs of hosts during cluster installation wizard
5. During connecting to agents error occurs.

**Note:** With ping command I am able to rich out to slaves from master.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pu60.png)

Answer (score 0):

@GrigVardanyan

Based on the image you provided, it looks like there is no resolve for the FQDNs from the ambari-server to the agents.  If it was able to connect the modal you click for FAILED will have much more detailed information.

Here are some very important points in very specific order:

1. You can install an agent on the Ambari Server too.
2. Make sure each servers hostname is set to the FQDN
3. Make sure /etc/hosts on Ambari Server, and Agent Servers defines all the FQDNs to the correct ip addresses.
4. Complete the steps to generate ssh keys on the Ambari Server (ssh-keygen)
5. Copy the Ambari Server SSH Public Key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) to all nodes file: ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
6. SSH from Ambari Server to each Agent Server to confirm SSH Keys work and allow password less login.  During first login you need to answer the prompt YES.
7. During cluster install wizard use the Ambari Server Private Key (~/.ssh/id_rsa) on the declare hosts page.  Let ambari use SSH to install, configure the agents.  If you complete it in this manner, you will not need to touch the agent configuration files.

Comment: I did as you mentioned. In agent logs it shows **can not switch user for run_command**
In ambari-server UI 
**==========================
Creating target directory...
==========================

Command start time 2020-06-02 23:27:30
**

Comment: what method are you following to install?   My reply above is assuming root user, and following standard ambari installation documentation.

Comment: Thanks for information. I changed to root. So another issue encountered
**Host registration aborted. Ambari Agent host cannot reach Ambari Server 'user-VirtualBox:8080'. Please check the network connectivity between the Ambari Agent host and the Ambari Server**

Comment: I recommend to use vagrant with virtual box per ambari quick start:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Quick+Start+Guide  It creates the ssh hosts and fqdn environments, for example I use c7301.ambari.apache.org.   just be sure to follow the directs exactly.